# View transitions and scroll restoration

Tags: google-chrome, view-transitions-api

I've noticed some odd behaviors with view transitions and scroll restoration in Chrome and I'm trying to understand if these are bugs or it is intended behavior. I can't find any official information on how they are supposed to behave in combination with scrolling.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehrencrona/2nhL7deo/12/) that emulates an SPA with two pages: one with a small blue ball at the end of the page and one with a large blue ball at the top of the page.

If I

- scroll to the end of page 1
- click "next" to go to page 2
- scroll up on page 2
- press back

Chrome will

- instantly scroll down page 2 to restore the scroll position
- start an animation of the ball that starts at its *new* position (that is higher on the page than it was when i pressed back)
- and then smoothly animate to page 1

That it first restores the scroll position before starting the animation results in a discontinuity in the animation that IMO completely destroys the point of it.

Am I doing something wrong, e.g. is there something wrong with how I do the SPA functionality, or is this a Chrome bug, or is it intended behavior?

--

This is the code:

```
let page = 0;

function render() {
  let body = '';

  if (page == 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      body += `<p>.</p>`;
    }

    body += `<div style="height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: blue; view-transition-name: bar"></div>`
  } else {
    body += `<div style="height: 300px; width: 300px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: blue; view-transition-name: bar"></div>`

    for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
      body += `<p>.</p>`;
    }
  }


  document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = body;
  document.querySelector('a').innerHTML = page == 0 ? 'Next' : 'Back';
}

render();

const useViewTransitions = true;

function transition() {
  if (useViewTransitions) {
    document.startViewTransition(render);
  } else {
    render();
  }
}

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click",
  async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (page == 0) {
      page++;

      history.pushState({
        page
      }, '');

      transition();
    } else {
      history.back();
    }
  }
);

window.addEventListener("popstate", ({
  state
}) => {
  page = state ? .page || 0;

  transition()
})
```

with the following HTML

```
<div style="height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 100%; background-color: red"></div>

<div id="content">
</div>

<a href="#"></a>
```

--

I hope the above description was comprehensible. Unfortunately I can't post a video, but this is the instant before I press back on page two (scrolled to the top of the page):

[image]

And this is an instant later when it scrolls me down before starting the animation

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with a view transition that involved a scroll. My solution was to defer slightly at the beginning and end of the transition function, e.g.

```js
document.startViewTransition(async () => {
  await 1;

  updateDOM();
  window.scrollTo({top: scrollY});
  
  await 1;
})
```

I think there is a slight race condition between creating the snapshot for the transition and setting the scroll position.